# Relativistic particle decay in ZMF

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

This is a problem that I feel is harder than I am making it but say you have:

A particle at rest of mass $M$ decays into two smaller particles of masses $m_1, m_2$ where $m_1 \neq m_2$ and $M > (m_1 + m_2)$.

The approximation $E \approx pc$ cannot be made.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit1:

So far, relating $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$ and considering conservation of 4-momentum has given me $2(pc)^2+c^4(m_1^2+m_2^2)+2E_1E_2=(Mc^2)^2$ which doesn't seem obviously solvable.

Other attempts have given that $(\gamma_1^2-1)m_1^2=(\gamma_2^2-1)m_2^2 $ from conservation of momentum. However substituting this result in doesn't not produce an (obviously) solvable equation for anything but $m_1=m_2$.

Edit 2:

Further research see [ref] has given the result that I am looking for as $E_1 = \frac{M^2-m_2^2+m_1^2}{2M}$, however attempts to get this result from first principles have proven fruitless.

Comment: I've edited the post to address issues brought up, please let me know if more must be done.

Comment: A couple problems: first, the post doesn't ask about the specific concept that's giving you trouble. You should show your progress toward solving the original homework question, identify the issue that you're stuck on, and ask about that sub-issue. Second, what are you supposed to be solving for, anyway? (This is why we advise people to quote the full text of the original problem.)

Comment: There are a couple other things, but these are not what's keeping your question on hold: (1) it's best not to mark your edits with "Edit 1:" "Edit 2:" etc. Don't mark them at all. When you edit, just make the post look like you'd written it that way in the first place. We don't care about marking which parts are new and which parts aren't. You can entirely rewrite it if you need to. (2) It's kind of weird that you use passive voice so much. But if that's your style, go for it. There isn't really anything _wrong_ with that.